# How to add current user details in log (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, slf4j

How can I add current user's details(user email ,...) in every logger.info() method?

it seems

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(sth.class)
```

instantiates
`ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`type by default.

as far as `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` is a final class so I can't extend to add my functionality.

what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way is using MDC.
Please check out this link for more information:
[How to use MDC of logback and SLF4J with spring boot to capture unique tracking in the POST request json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563316/how-to-use-mdc-of-logback-and-slf4j-with-spring-boot-to-capture-unique-tracking)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented this using Spring Boot v2.7.

First define a custom filter that will add the user data to MDC:

```kotlin
import org.slf4j.MDC
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticatedPrincipal
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@Component
class UserMdcFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    companion object {
        private const val USER_MDC_KEY = "user"
    }

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication?.principal as? AuthenticatedPrincipal
        if (principal != null) {
            val user = principal.name
            MDC.put(USER_MDC_KEY, user)
        }

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(USER_MDC_KEY)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add the filter in your Spring Security configuration.

```kotlin
// I do it after FilterSecurityInterceptor, otherwise authenticated context is not set
http.addFilterAfter(userMdcFilter, FilterSecurityInterceptor::class.java)
```

You can view the data by modifying your log pattern to include MDC:

```xml
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <Pattern>
            %clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr([%mdc]){yellow} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}
        </Pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

This is the default Spring console log pattern, except `%clr([%mdc]){yellow}` is added.

End result:

```bash
2023-05-16 01:23:14.346 DEBUG [,06bfe7e72b5007e0,06bfe7e72b5007e0] 77570 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] [user=bf11c59b-eaca-47cd-a9d4-77cd62181e55] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) and then using that value in the [log pattern](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#mdc) is the way to go.

For a spring boot web app just add a filter after the [SecurityContextHolderFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextHolderFilter.html) with the security filter chain API.

A simple example for a filter configuration:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.addFilterAfter((servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain) -> {
                try {
                    // get the username from current user's authentication
                    Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                            .ifPresent(authentication -> MDC.put("user-name", authentication.getName()));
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                } finally {
                    MDC.remove("user-name");
                }
            }, SecurityContextHolderFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> ....)
            .build();
}
```

Configure the slf4j(logback) pattern to use the mdc value in your `application.yaml`.

In the following pattern `%mdc{user-name:-NO_USER}` will use the user's user name set in the filter or `NO_USER` if the user-name variable is not set.

```
logging.pattern.console: "[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %-5level [%mdc{user-name:-NO_USER}] [%t{15}] [%logger{36}-:%line]: %m%n"
```